# Upload multiple files to Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Up until now I've been using the upload a file to drive demo code. However, for my application I need to be able to upload multiple user selected files with one click of a button. My problem is that instead of upload each file to Drive it will upload the last file selected once for every file thats been selected. I think if I understand it correctly the cause of this has something to do the IntentSender being executed multiple times quickly and returning to the `REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR` case but I'm unable to see another way to structure the code.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_LAUNCH_MAIN:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                for (int i = 0; i<bundle.size()/2; i++) {
                    file = bundle.getByteArray(DATA+i);
                    directory = new Directory(bundle.getString(PATH+i));
                    Log.i(TAG, bundle.getString(PATH+i) + " extracted");
                    uploadFileToDrive();
                    Log.i(TAG, bundle.getString(PATH+i) + " uploaded");
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Finished Uploading", 0).show();
            break;
        case REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR:
            // Called after a file is saved to Drive.
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Files successfully saved.");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Starting new process", 0).show();
                file = null;
                // Return to the Main UI to select more apps ect.
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class),
                        REQUEST_CODE_LAUNCH_MAIN);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

`uploadToDrive()` method

```
public void uploadFileToDrive() {
    // Start by creating a new contents, and setting a callback.
    Log.i(TAG, "Creating new contents.");
    Drive.DriveApi.newContents(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.ContentsResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveApi.ContentsResult result) {

            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.");
                return;
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "New contents created.");
            OutputStream outputStream = result.getContents().getOutputStream();

            try {
                outputStream.write(file);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Unable to write file contents.");
            }

            // Create the initial metadata - MIME type and title.
            // Note that the user will be able to change the title later.
            MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setMimeType("application/zip")
                    .setTitle(directory.getZipFileName())
                    .build();

            // Create an intent for the file chooser, and start it.
            IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                    .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                    .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                    .setInitialContents(result.getContents())
                    .build(googleApiClient);

            try {
                startIntentSenderForResult(
                        intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Failed to launch file chooser.");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution is to make `file` and `directory` parameters to the `uploadFileToDrive()` function. Right now your code is referencing the single global copy of those variables, and the callbacks are likely only firing after the last iteration in the for loop is complete.