# How to upload all the audio files in a directory to the google drive?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am facing the issue in uploading the list of audio to google drive.

I can upload the single audio file from a directory but i tried to upload the list of audio files is failed.

This is the path for the single audio file

```
final String path = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CallLogs/Yaendi Yaendi.mp3");
```

How to upload the all the audio files in the CallLogs directory.

```
public void CreateFileOnGoogleDrive(DriveApi.DriveContentsResult result) {

        final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();

        // Perform I/O off the UI thread.
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // write content to DriveContents


                OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();

                final String path = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/CallLogs/Yaendi Yaendi.mp3");

                FileInputStream inputStream = null;

                try {
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    showErrorDialog();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                try {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                            outputStream.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    showErrorDialog();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

 MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setTitle("callLog")
                        .setMimeType("audio/mpeg")
                        .setStarred(true).build();


                // create a file in root folder
                Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(mGoogleApiClient)
                        .createFile(mGoogleApiClient, changeSet, driveContents).setResultCallback(fileCallback);

            }
        }.start();

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Created Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The above code is for uploading the single audio file to google drive.
Please help me how to upload the all the files to the google drive.

Comment: You might want to check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33520802/5995040) and [Upload multiple files to Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23946030/5995040) that talks about setting up a variable to list all files that you have to upload then create a loop for while there is a file to be uploaded. You can also try batch request for creating/uploading files (thru asynctask) as stated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35005843/5995040). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Place your code inside AsyncTask's `doInBackground()` method.